# Change the selected value of a select box and submit form - not working in IE

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
<select size="1" id="this_emp_id" onchange="showProcessing();form.submit()">
<option value="">Choose</option>
<option value="ahr5r759797">Ahrbecker, Lisa M</option>
<option value="baryxr77ata">Barrera Garrido, Antonio</option>
<option value="baug97ee9tx">Baurley, Janet L</option>
<option value="bel7bhh3m93">Belschner, Chad Matthew</option>
<option value="bie55ed9393">Bielefeld, Emily Margaret</option>
```

… with many more learners

Using a separate find learner routine I get the value of a learner and use the following to change the value of the above select box:

```
empSelect = document.getElementById("this_emp_id");
empSelect.options[0].value = retVal;
empSelect.options[0].selected = true;
formObj.submit();
```

This works perfect except in IE even in Edge it does not work, is there an alternative for IE?

Comment: Any errors thrown in IE dev tools console?

Comment: You have no `name` attribute on your `<select>`, is that a copying error?

Comment: No errors the dev tools.

Comment: Why do you have `form.submit()` in the `onchange` and also `formObj.submit()` in the Javascript?

Comment: Sorry, I removed the name in this, it does have the name.

Comment: The `form.submit()` is based on a button click, I did not include all of the code as it is very, very long.  I have a separate part of the code that finds a value and using the found value I want to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `selectedIndex` of the select element, rather than setting the `selected` property of the option.

```
empSelect.selectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I have tried that too, does not work in IE

Comment: I tested http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/a4s7mu2r/11/ in Edge and it works. I can't seem to open it in IE11 in BrowserStack (I don't have a real Windows machine of my own).

Comment: It does actually change the select box, but it does not work with the submit, if you change the name of `showProcessing()' function to 'changeSelect()` and add a button to trigger `changeSelect()` you have a good example of the issue.

Comment: It works with submit. The script my jsfiddle submits to displays the submitted value, and you can see that it displays `TestValue`.

Comment: Feel free to edit my fiddle to show the changes that make it not work.

Comment: Your code does not include the `formObj.submit()`, you are selecting an option from the select list, as I have mentioned, the selecting is made in another part of the code.

Comment: My code has `this.form.submit()` in the `onchange`. That's the same as `formObj.submit()`

Comment: I have changed you code but this is my first time using jsfiddle and I don't know how to run the code as it does nothing when I click the "Run.

Comment: It should show the form in the bottom right box, then you can select from the dropdown to change it, and click on the Submit button.

Comment: I just copied your code, you have it in `onchange`. What difference does it make, they do the same thing.?

Comment: Your form has no ID it needs to be "search", the button is not a "submit" and the JavaScript does not include code to get the form and then do a formObj.submit()

Comment: My form has `<input type="submit">`. Clicking on that is the same as calling `formObj.submit()`.

Comment: This is getting really tiring, you're complaining about things that make no difference to what you're trying to do. Please edit my fiddle to do it the way you want, and see if it works or not.

Comment: I'm really sorry about this, I just can't get fiddler working for me. I will put up another detailed question with full code - thanks.

Comment: Don't post a new question. Edit this question.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/a4s7mu2r/26/ I've added `formObj.submit()` to the `changeForm()` function.

Comment: The code is now a very good example, however, in the bottom right hand box using Edge I get "Microsoft Edge can’t get to this page" and in Chrome I get nothing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, unfortunately, I have an appointment and must leaver this for a few days - thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, I found the problem, it was a form within a form, the page is a server side page and id 900+ lines long.  Sorry for the inconvenience.